# Python noob-- Probably a simple typo?

Tags: python

I really just can't understand why this code is not working... 
It's probably just a typo. But even my more experienced friend is stumped here. 
The prompt is simply "write a program that tells you how many 4s there are in a given list." Its all working except that count says zero no matter how many 4s I submit.

```
def num_four(number_list): 
    count = 0

    print number_list
    for i in number_list:
        print i
        if i == 4:  
            count = count + 1
    return count
number_list = raw_input("Enter list of integers here: ")

print num_four(number_list)
```

the output looks like this:

```
Enter list of integers here: 123444
123444
1
2
3
4
4
4
0
```

Answer (score 6):

`raw_input` returns a string like `"8675409"`. When you iterate over this string (it's not a list), you get the string `"8"`, then `"6"`, then `"7"` -- it will eventually be `"4"`, but never be the int `4`.

Comment: All I can think of when I read your answer "Jenny I got your number". Only one digit off. :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you don't pass a list of numbers to your function because `raw_input` returns a string.

```
number_list = raw_input("Enter list of integers here: ")
number_list = map(int, number_list.split())
print num_four(number_list)
```

This assumes that the numbers you input are separated by whitespace.
If you just put in strings like '1234', iterate over the string and check against `'4'` instead of the integer `4` in your function. If that's the case, consider renaming `number_list` to something more fitting like `continuous_number_string`.

And if you want to simplify your function, use the count method of either `str` or `list`:

```
>>> [1,2,3,4,4,5].count(4)
2
>>> '1234544'.count('4')
3
```

Answer (score 0):

`raw_input` will produce a string, not a list of integers, regardless of what you type in. So `i` will never equal 4 (integer) at most "4" (string).

Answer (score 0):

Please check the answer of @Mike Graham.

And just in case you are looking for a more Pythonic solution:

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(raw_input()).get("4")
```